# TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function jest

Tags: typescript, npm, jestjs

When running 'npm test' getting the following error:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/unit/domain/services/demo-service.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

      at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:357:15)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:419:28)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:523:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

Answer (score 19):

`ts-jest` major version must match `jest` major version; e.g.

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "ts-jest": "^26.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Might be the issue with the version of **jest**, I tried to use **26.5.5** which worked for me.

If you are using npm, there are some packages you could install:

```
npm install jest@26.5.5 --save-dev
npm install ts-jest --save-dev
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install ts-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the config uses `babel-jest` + `@babel/preset-typescript` instead of `ts-jest`.

Therefore, I had to make sure `babel-jest` and `jest` had the same major version.

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.16.7",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest": "26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was initially using `jest v24.x.x`. I faced this transformer issue when I updated to `v 27.5.1`.

I wasn't using a TS based project so there wasn't a `ts-jest` dependency. I fixed the issue by changing the

```js
transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(css|scss)$': 'jest-css-module',
  },
```

to

```js
transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(css|scss)$': 'jest-css-modules-transform', // made change here
  },
```

Moreover, I had to add

```json
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
```

property into the jest config because now jest supports different environments for testing (it was not the case in `v24.x.x`).

In case you make a test which makes use of `node` env, you will have to install `core-js` package and `import` it into the specific test file.